# SQLite makes a folder with the DLL file

Tags: c#, sqlite

So I've been struggling for a while now.
In my Release folder of the program there is an x86 and x64 folder of SQLite which in both of them has the SQLite DLL.
I am using the Costura.Fody plugin, so how could I get the DLL from the x86 folder compile inside the exe with Costura.Fody?

Tried copying the DLL from x86 to the Release folder:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: A DLL (Dynamic Link Library) isn't meant to be compiled into an executable. Information about it is placed into the exe, and it is loaded _dynamically_ at run time.

Comment: How could i make my program a single file then?

Comment: Here's a good example of what I think you are looking for: https://github.com/matjazbravc/Embedded-SQLite-Demo

Since there is a 32 bit and 64 bit version of the same dll, you have to put them in special folders that Costura recognizes, and explicitly include them in the FodyWeavers.xml

Comment: Thanks, I figured a different solution, using web client I download the dll inside the current directory where the exe is launched before I start using the sql.